# mysql не пускает через phpadmin, но в сам mysql дает

Tags: php, mysql, apache

суть проблемы - стоит связка mysql/apache/php работало до вчерашнего дня лет 10. при заходе на phpadmin под рутом не пускает без указания ошибки. пишет Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL. При сам MySql работает и в консоле в под рутом пускает. Показывает базы/таблицы. то есть проблемы не с паролями. что это может быть?

Comment: проблема может быть в чем угодно! Нужно изучать логи, телепатией решить такие вопросы сложно.

Comment: Без отказный SQL  ?)

Answer (score 0):

Так и должно быть нельзя под рутом заходить в phpMyAdmin. Вероятно работает mysql_secure_installation.

Решыть просто, создай нового пользователя, дай ему рут права, то есть все и заходи под ним.

```
mysql -u NAME_USER -p

CREATE USER 'non-root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
```

В этой команде, ‘non-root’ – это имя, которое мы назначаем нашему новому пользователю. А ‘123’ – это его пароль. Вы можете заменить на свои значения внутри кавычек.

Чтобы назначить вновь созданном пользователю неограниченные права доступа к базе данных, выполните следующую команду:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'non-root'@'localhost';
```

Для того, чтоб изменения вошли в силу запустите команду обновления:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Хех. Проблему решил сам. Включил логирование в MySQL. Там на все попытки зайти на сайт/PHP раздел связанный с SQL были ошибки доступа.

В результате нашел в hosts строчку 
192.168.1.1 localhost
- удалил ее и все заработало. И phpMyAdmin и доступ извне.